# Can't do a src to node modules folder

Tags: customization, directory

I'm trying to use `GLide.js` and after installing it with npm, i'm trying to access it using `script src`

This is the code i'm using

```
<script src="<?php  echo ABSPATH.'/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.min.js';?>"></script>
```

I know wordpress has specific methods to acess folder for example:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/navbar.js"></script>
```

but since node modules is in root , i'm guessing there's another one

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ABSPATH` is a directory path not an URL, use `site_url()` or `home_url()` instead.

Comment: nevermind , slow loading, you fixed it thanks !

Comment: missing an echo, and you can put the path as the first argument if you want to: eg. `<script src="<?php echo site_url('/node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.min.js'); ?>"></script>`

Comment: You should use the enqueue script system rather than hardcoding the script tags